# ERROR : $ hadoop namenode -format

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

When I run `hadoop namenode -format` command, I get the following error:

```
14/05/10 09:51:36 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
14/05/10 09:51:36 ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:1337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:1356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)

14/05/10 09:51:36 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at chirag/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you check once namenode is running or if it is not running you need to run once. And it need create dir in /app it need permissions. Type this bellow commands:

sudo mkdir /app

sudo chown $USER /app

hadoop namenode -format

Then start all nodes and check after few minutes. It will run all nodes..................